# multiple order instances created when the page is refreshing

Tags: python, django, function, web, view

I'm getting the billing address and display it in the payments page but the problem is that when i refresh the page it's create an other instance in the admin panel I tried the get_or_create but it still the same

```
def placeorder(request, total=0, quantity=0):
    current_user = request.user
    cart_itemes = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_itemes.count()

    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')
    # order_data=request.session.get('context')
    # if order_data:
    #     return render(request,'orders/payments.html')

    for cart_item in cart_itemes:

        total += (cart_item.product.price*cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    totale = total
    finaltotal = totale+50

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = OrderForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            data.address_line1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line1']
            data.address_line2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            # data = Order(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, phone_number=phone_number,
            #              address_line1=address_line1, address_line2=address_line2, country=country, state=state, city=city)
            data.order_total = totale
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr, mt, dt)
            current_date = d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()

            order = get_object_or_404(Order,
                                      user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_number)
            context = {
                "order": order,
                "cart_itemes": cart_itemes,
                "total": totale,
                "finaltotal": finaltotal
            }
            # request.session['context']=context
            return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', context)

        else:
            pass

    else:

        return redirect('checkout')
```

this the view that handlle that placing order ,the data returned in the payments.html is correctly displayed and it's fine but why it's always becoms multiple in django when I refresh the page

Comment: how should I do that